# Jquery hide and show css

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have some problems with code . 
So i want to show Div (table) with jquery. 
And i can't do this.

Code HTML:

```html
<div id="DT12345-1234-123">
 <table>
  (Some table details)
 </table>
</div>
```

Code CSS:

```css
#DT12345-1234-123 {
    display: none;
}
```

Code Jquery:

```js
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('#button').on('click', function(){
        var number;
        number = $('#write_something').val();

        if (number == 'DT12345-1234-123')
        {
            $("#DT12345-1234-123").css("display", "block");
        }

    });

});
```

Code HTML(button , input):

```
<form class="cs_booking_form">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
   <div class="form-group">
    <input id="write_something" type="text" class="form-control" 
    placeholder="Your Number">
   </div>
  </div>
  div class="cs_btndiv">
   <button id="button" class="cs_btn cs_white_btn">Do</button>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div id="DT12345-1234-123">
  <table>
  (some in table)
  </table>
 </div>
</form>
```

the table is displayed for only a millisecond and then restart cite . And the same table is not open

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Where is the button that you click? Can you show more of the code?

Comment: Definitely show the HTML for the button. I bet pressing the button is submitting, which causes the page to reload if the button is not part of a `<form>` and/or there is no `action` for it.

Comment: Yes , of course. Added

Comment: Also can programmatically prevent form submit by doing `$('#button').click(function(event){event.preventDefault(); var number...`

Answer (score 2):

By default `<button>` is a `type="submit"`.
To override that default behavior (form submission) use **`type="button"`**

```
<button type="button" id="button" class="cs_btn cs_white_btn">Do</button>
```

Also `$('document').ready(function(){` Should be `$(document).ready(function(){` or rather

```
jQuery(function( $ ){ // DOM ready and $ alias in scope
```

or if you prefer ES6 syntax: `jQuery( $ => {`

Additionally you can prevent browser defaults by using `Event.preventDefault()`:

```
jQuery(function( $ ){
    $('#button').on('click', function(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();

        var str = $('#write_something').val();

        if (str === 'DT12345-1234-123') {
            $("#"+ str ).css("display", "block");
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Omg , i was forgot this . Thx you so mush +rep